# Trying to fetch json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, rest

I am trying to fetch json data from this url- "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos". And I am following this flutter cookbook tutorial - "https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing"

My model class looks like this-

```
class ModelData {
          ModelData({
            this.albumId,
            this.id,
            this.title,
            this.url,
            this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

     final int albumId;
     final int id;
     final String title;
     final String url;
     final String thumbnailUrl;



factory ModelData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ModelData(
albumId: json["albumId"] as int,
id: json["id"] as int,
title: json["title"] as String,
url: json["url"] as String,
thumbnailUrl: json["thumbnailUrl"] as String,
 );
 }
```

And my parseData method looks like this-

```
List<ModelData> parseData(String responseBody) {
final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

return parsed
    .map<ModelData>((json) => ModelData().fromJson(json)).toList();
```

}

The problem is in the last line of this method. It says "error: The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'ModelData'. (undefined_method at [flutter_rest] lib\main.dart:61)". i don't see any typo problem here. What might going wrong here?

Comment: ModelData().fromJson(json) change it to ModelData.fromJson(json). Factory methods work like static functions

Answer (score 3):

Factory methods act like a static method but you are initialising the class by using `ModelData()`.
Try like this:

```dart
ModelData.fromJson(json)
```